# Keyboard capslock does not work as expected sometimes

Tags: keyboard

My husband has converted the entire household to Ubuntu, so far things are going fine, except for this small issue, I have a ps/2 Genius keyboard model, KB-06X attached to a desktop computer and on rare occasions when I am typing in any application, Word processor, text editor or forms and I activate capslock what I get are lower case characters, when I deactivate capslock (green light off) I got upper case characters, I noticed this as far back as  8.04 and as recent as 10.04, I have not noticed it yet on 10.1, even if 10.1 fixes the problem I am still curious as to why this happen on the others.

Is it just cheap faulty keyboard or is this a known problem?

Comment: Have you tried taking the caps lock key off and removing any cruft/food/etc? You could also try using the keyboard on Windows.

Comment: When this occurred the keyboard was new, I have a habit of keeping my input devices in good condition, The only Windows we have now are the ones that let light and air into the house :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a forum topic which might be usefull.

[[SOLVED] Caps lock light reversed](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=784935)

It covers a selection of different solutions so hopefully one will work

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The internal state of the software interpreting caps lock is distinct from the lights used to display caps lock. At least on my machine (Lenovo Y50), the caps lock indicator light on my laptop keyboard is only switched on and off when the caps lock button on that keyboard is pressed; pressing the button on my USB keyboard switches caps lock on and off but doesn't toggle the indicator.

So to fix the reversing, press caps lock on the USB keyboard until the actual state matches the light (typing a few characters to test), then use the laptop keyboard to turn it off if it is on.

Answer (score 0):

No need to look at the forum. 
The best way is to open the "onboard" (on-screen keyboard):

```
$onboard
```

Press the cap lock using your mouse and exit the onboard.
Problem solved.